# Supremum and maximum

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I'm asked to tell whether the supremum and maximum of the following functions exist and to derive them when $x \in B$:

$1- B = [0, 4 \pi)~\text{and}~g(x)=\cos x$

$2- B = [0, 4 \pi)~\text{and}~g(x)=\sin^2x+\cos^2x$

For the first one, I found that $\max f(x)_{x \in B}$ doesn't exist and $\sup f(x)_{x \in B} = -\infty$. Is it correct ?

For the second one, I need help.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you conclude 1?

Comment: Is that $1-B$? Or is that $B$ for problem 1? What is $f(x)$? The problems say $g(x)$. Can cosine ever equal negative 2?

Comment: No, B for problem 1.  I meant for the answer $g(x).$

Comment: I've been doing some kind of framing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: your conclusion for the first one seems absurd, since $\cos x$ takes values in $[-1,1]$. For the second, observe that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.

Comment: Does this means that $\max f(x)_{x \in B} = \sup f(x)_{x \in B} = 1$ for the first one ?

Comment: The function $\cos $ reaches its maximum at e.g. $0$, so since $B$ contains $0$ maximum and supremum coincide.

Comment: For the second one, $\max g(x)_{x \in B} = \sup g(x)_{x \in B} = 1$. Is it good ?

Comment: Yes, because the function is constant.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. There's one more thing I didn't understand. How do you know that $\cos x$ takes values in $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Because of the definition of $\cos$ (and $\sin$).

Comment: Okay. For the first one, $\arg\max_{x} f(x) = 0$. Right ?